# open images as pop up in PHP (WordPress) or scroll to image opened

Tags: php, wordpress, function

Hi (sorry for my next english :))
i need help in a wordpress template oneengine in which in the portfolio images the photos are open down the timeline of the photos without an automatically scroll down, like that:

[image: 50% off zoom]

the fact could be 1) I need a code to scroll down or 2) I need a popup view here the code of the function.php:

```
<?php
        }
    }
    wp_reset_query();
    echo '</div>';
    echo '<div id="portfolio_content">
             <div class="container">
                 <div class="row">
                     <div class="port-control col-md-12">
                         <div class="port-content"> 
                         </div>
                         <a class="prev" href="#"><span class="arrow-port left"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;'.__('Prev','oneengine').'</a> 
                         <a href="#" class="close-port"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a> 
                         <a href="#" class="next">'.__('Next','oneengine').'&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="arrow-port right"></span></a>
                     </div>
                 </div>
             </div>
         </div>';               
     }

     function before_block( $instance ) {
         extract( $instance );
         echo '<div id="aq-block-'.$template_id.'-'.$number.'" class="aq-block aq-block-'.$id_base.'">';
         echo '<div id="portfolio-page" class="portfolio-wrapper" style="margin:'.$margin_top.'px 0 '.$margin_bottom.'px;">';
     }

     function after_block( $instance ) {
         extract( $instance );
         echo '</div>';
         echo '</div><!-- END ET-PORTFOLIO-BLOCK-->';
     }
 }
```

for all the documentation the theme is OneEngine https://www.enginethemes.com/themes/oneengine/

Comment: You should be able to come up with some css, javascript or jquery code to do that. show us those file so that we can see where to help you as we do not manufacture code  or do some one assignment here

Comment: from Functions.php  file : 
    <div class="row">
     <div class="title-port-wrapper col-md-12">
      <h1 class="title-port">'.$portfolio->post_title.'</h1>
      <span class="category">'.$cats.'</span>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="port-data">
<div id="port">
     <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-8 port-thumb">
       <div class="thumbnail-img">
        '.get_the_post_thumbnail( $portfolio->ID, 'full' ).'
       </div>
      </div>

</div>
         </div>
    </div>';